# Service stops working after sometime. Needed to work continuously

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I am developing a step counter app where I count the number of steps walked and update it to the server at midnight. I have a service running continuously to do all this.

**Here is my service:**

```
    public class StepCounterService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, StepListener, WebServiceInterface, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int SERVICE_ID = 27;
    private static final int SEND_SESSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int SEND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int MAIN_NOTIFICATION_ID = 3;
    private static final int SECONDARY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 4;
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

    static final public String STEP_INCREMENT = "com.app.STEP_INCREMENTED";
    static final public String SESSION_COMPLETE = "com.app.SESSION_COMPLETE";
    static final public String ACTIVITY_COMPLETE = "com.app.ACTIVITY_COMPLETE";
    static final public String STEP_INCREMENT_KEY = "step_count";

    Session session;

    private StepDetector stepDetector;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private int numberOfSteps = 0;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    double currentLatitude;
    double currentLongitude;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListLocations;
    private AlarmManager sendActivityAlarmManager;
    private PendingIntent activityAlarmIntent;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    RemoteViews contentView;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    private String TAG = "Wake Lock Tag";
    private int SET_LAST_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 5;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("---- In onTaskRemoved Function");
        restartKilledService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("---- In onDestroy Function");
        if (wl != null) {
            wl.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        restartKilledService();
    }

    void restartKilledService() {

        System.out.println("---- In restartKilledService Function");

        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StepCounterService.class);
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), StepCounterService.SERVICE_ID, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, restartServicePI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        wl.acquire();

        super.onCreate();

        session = new Session(this);
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        stepDetector = new StepDetector();
        stepDetector.registerListener(StepCounterService.this);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long interval = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes in milliseconds
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(ctx, StepCounterService.class);

        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, StepCounterService.SERVICE_ID, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, servicePendingIntent);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notif_icon);

        if (session.getUser() != null && !(session.getUser().getName().equals("")))
            updateMainNotification(session.getTodaySteps() + "");

        startAlarm();
    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            stepDetector.updateAccel(event.timestamp, event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void step(long timeNs) {
        numberOfSteps = session.getTodaySteps();
        numberOfSteps++;

        sendStepIncrementBroadcast(numberOfSteps);

        session.setTodaySteps(numberOfSteps);

        if (session.getUser() != null && !(session.getUser().getName().equals("")))
            updateMainNotification(numberOfSteps + "");
        else {
            try {
                notificationManager.cancel(MAIN_NOTIFICATION_ID);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void sendStepIncrementBroadcast(int numberOfSteps) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(STEP_INCREMENT);
        intent.putExtra(STEP_INCREMENT_KEY, numberOfSteps);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    public float[] getDataFromSteps(int stepsCount) {
        float caloriesCount = 0;
        float creditsCount = 0;
        try {
            double adjustedWeight = Double.parseDouble(session.getUser().getWeight()) / LinksAndKeys.weightAdjuster;
            caloriesCount = Math.round(((adjustedWeight * LinksAndKeys.metValue) / LinksAndKeys.setPace) * (stepsCount / LinksAndKeys.stepsPerMile));
            caloriesCount = caloriesCount * 1.2f;
            creditsCount = caloriesCount / 25.4f;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            caloriesCount = 0;
            creditsCount = 0;
        }

        float[] resultantFloat = {caloriesCount, creditsCount};
        return resultantFloat;
    }

    private void startAlarm() {

        sendActivityAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityCompleteReceiver.class);
        activityAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
//        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, generateRandomTime()[0]);
//        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, generateRandomTime()[1]);

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

        sendActivityAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, activityAlarmIntent);
    }

    private void updateMainNotification(String stepsValue) {

        String title = "Today: " + stepsValue + " steps - " + LinksAndKeys.decimalFormat.format(getDataFromSteps(session.getTodaySteps())[1]) + " FIMOs";
        String message = "Keep Walking and Keep Earning";

        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewTitle, title);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewMessage, message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(StepCounterService.this, SplashActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(StepCounterService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.running_icon)
                .setContent(contentView).setContentIntent(intent);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
//        notificationManager.notify(MAIN_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        startForeground(MAIN_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void updateReminderNotification() {

        String title = "A gentle reminder";
        String message = "Its time to get on track";

        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewTitle, title);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewMessage, message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(StepCounterService.this, SplashActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(StepCounterService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.running_icon)
                .setContent(contentView).setContentIntent(intent);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(SECONDARY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private int[] generateRandomTime() {
        int[] timeIntegers = new int[2];

        final Random r = new Random();
        timeIntegers[0] = r.nextInt(58 - 56) + 56;
        timeIntegers[1] = r.nextInt(59 - 1) + 1;

        return timeIntegers;
    }
}
```

**Here is the Activity Complete Receiver:**

```
public class ActivityCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements WebServiceInterface {

    Session session;
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
    static final public String ACTIVITY_COMPLETE = "com.fimo.ACTIVITY_COMPLETE";
    private static final int SEND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    Gson gson;
    MyDatabase myDatabase;
    UserActivity currentUserActivity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        session = new Session(context);
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
        myDatabase = new MyDatabase(context);
        gson = new Gson();

        sendActivityToServer(context, session.getUser().getId(), session.getTodaySteps());
    }

    private void sendActivityToServer(Context context, String id, int steps) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

        UserActivity userActivity = new UserActivity();
        userActivity.setDate(date);
        userActivity.setSteps(steps);
        userActivity.setCalories(getDataFromSteps(steps)[0]);
        userActivity.setCredits(getDataFromSteps(steps)[1]);

        currentUserActivity = userActivity;

        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            HashMap<String, String> paramsList = new HashMap<>();
            ArrayList<UserActivity> arrayListUserActivity = myDatabase.getAllUserActivities();
            arrayListUserActivity.add(userActivity);

            paramsList.put(LinksAndKeys.ID_KEY, id);
            paramsList.put(LinksAndKeys.DATA_KEY, gson.toJson(arrayListUserActivity));

            Log.d("Receiver Request ----", id + " - " + gson.toJson(arrayListUserActivity));

            WebServiceController webServiceController = new WebServiceController(
                    context, ActivityCompleteReceiver.this);
            String hitURL = LinksAndKeys.SEND_ACTIVITY_URL;
            webServiceController.sendSilentRequest(false, hitURL, paramsList, SEND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            myDatabase.addUserActivity(currentUserActivity);
            currentUserActivity = null;

            Intent in = new Intent(ACTIVITY_COMPLETE);
            broadcaster.sendBroadcast(in);

            session.setTodaySteps(0);
        }

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void getResponse(int responseCode, String responseString, String requestType, int requestCode) {
        if (requestCode == SEND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == 200) {
            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                String message = responseObject.getString("message");
                if (message.equals("Success")) {

                    myDatabase.deleteAllUserActivities();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = responseObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    session.setServerCredits(Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getString("credits")));

                    Intent in = new Intent(ACTIVITY_COMPLETE);
                    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(in);

                    session.setTodaySteps(0);
                } else {
                    myDatabase.addUserActivity(currentUserActivity);
                    currentUserActivity = null;

                    Intent in = new Intent(ACTIVITY_COMPLETE);
                    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(in);

                    session.setTodaySteps(0);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                myDatabase.addUserActivity(currentUserActivity);
                currentUserActivity = null;

                Intent in = new Intent(ACTIVITY_COMPLETE);
                broadcaster.sendBroadcast(in);

                session.setTodaySteps(0);
            }
        } else {
            if (currentUserActivity != null) {
                myDatabase.addUserActivity(currentUserActivity);
                currentUserActivity = null;

                Intent in = new Intent(ACTIVITY_COMPLETE);
                broadcaster.sendBroadcast(in);

                session.setTodaySteps(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public float[] getDataFromSteps(int stepsCount) {
        float caloriesCount = 0;
        float creditsCount = 0;
        try {
            double adjustedWeight = Double.parseDouble(session.getUser().getWeight()) / LinksAndKeys.weightAdjuster;
            caloriesCount = Math.round(((adjustedWeight * LinksAndKeys.metValue) / LinksAndKeys.setPace) * (stepsCount / LinksAndKeys.stepsPerMile));
            caloriesCount = caloriesCount * 1.2f;
            creditsCount = caloriesCount / 25.4f;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            caloriesCount = 0;
            creditsCount = 0;
        }

        float[] resultantFloat = {caloriesCount, creditsCount};
        return resultantFloat;
    }
}
```

***The code written is supposed to behave on this way:***

Everyday count the number of steps taken by the user. -> At midnight at a particular time between 11.56-11.59, send the data to activity complete receiver -> The receiver receives the data and tries to send it to the server if internet is available. If not, then it saves it to local database -> After saving or sending, reset the steps to 0 and service starts counting again from 0 for the next day.

The problem is the service is not actually working some days at the given time and receiver does not receive the activity complete intent. If I keep the phone on and test it by setting a time which is a few minutes from current time, service works. But if the phone is kept untouched from a long time then I think this case happens as the service stops working. This is my guess, the actual problem might be something else. Any suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please switch the service to a process in manifest and try. Or try foreground Service. Service may stops after some time

Comment: Android closes services when there is low memory issue with device you can start service on onTerminate() of your service or you can send a broadcast on onDestroy() of service and using receiver you can start the service again.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43230330/5241933) help?

Comment: Its for general people to use. It will go to play store.

Comment: You are holding a partial wakelock when your `Service` is running. The device will never be able to go to sleep and you will drain the battery. Users will uninstall your app immediately.

Comment: When you try to restart your killed `Service`, you are passing incompatible arguments to `AlarmManager.set()`. You specify `RTC_WAKEUP`, but use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` as the time parameter. Using `RTC_WAKEUP` expects `System.currentTimeMillis()`, not elapsed time.

Comment: Why do you schedule a repeating alarm to run your `Service` every 5 minutes, when it is already running?

Comment: You can't. One way to make it works as you want is to use some *hack* like AlarmManager etc.. but do not expect that a STICKY service will run forever. Android does not like that king of stuff, it will kill the service.. always!

Answer (score 2):

As of API level 19, using `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` which you are doing to call your `ActivityCompleteReceiver`, is not reliably accurate. Android can delay the delivery of this alarm if it wants to. If you really want this to be triggered at an exact time each day you should do the following:

Use `AlarmManager.setExact()` and set one alarm (not a repeating alarm) for the next trigger time. When this alarm gets delivered, send your statistics or whatever you want and then call `AlarmManager.setExact()` to set the next alarm (for the next day). You should avoid using `setRepeating()` unless you absolutely need to use it.

You need to watch what you are doing with wake locks, as your current code keeps a partial wake lock all the time and this will prevent the device from going to sleep which will drain the battery. Read up on how to optimize battery use.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running into Doze mode restrictions, introduced in [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) and split into Light and Deep Doze in [Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#doze):

> When a device is on battery power, and the screen has been off for a certain time, the device enters Doze and applies the first subset of restrictions: It shuts off app network access, and defers jobs and syncs. If the device is stationary for a certain time after entering Doze, the system applies the rest of the Doze restrictions to PowerManager.WakeLock, AlarmManager alarms, GPS, and Wi-Fi scans. Regardless of whether some or all Doze restrictions are being applied, the system wakes the device for brief maintenance windows, during which applications are allowed network access and can execute any deferred jobs/syncs.

So even if you manage to get an alarm to fire, e.g. with `setAndAllowWhileIdle()`, you still won't have network access. The usual recommendation is to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) or something like it e.g. [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/) and [Evernote Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). These frameworks allow configuration of jobs that will run when network becomes available, e.g. with [`JobInfo.Builder.setRequiredNetworkType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int)). The timing will be at the mercy of when Doze goes into its "idle maintenance" window, but at least you know you'll have network access when it happens.

If more control over timing is required, it may be possible to set an alarm that will wake while idle, and then use GCM/FCM high priority messages to force network access. I'm not sure how you pick those up on the Firebase end though -- that would be up to your server side code.

Answer (score 1):

•A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.

1:Start Notification With Service Using startForeground.

2:return START_STICKY from OnCommandStart.

```
 private void showLocationNotification()
    {
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Service")
                .setContentText("Service Started Successfully")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

On Create Call Above method

3.Manifest file in Your Service tag put this `android:stopWithTask="false"`

Comment: The default value of stopWithTask is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your main problem is that Android is not a system designed to run things continuously.

Even using a service and even using startForeground there is no guarantee that your process will not be killed by the system at any time.

Android isn't an OS for servers. The probability of a service being killed during the first few hours is low but after 2 or 3 days becomes very high

A main priority on Android is to save battery over keeping some service running.

Also with your design it is clear that your application will score very high in battery drain apps due what you intend does not allow the device to enter in deep sleep and surely the user will have to charge the battery more than once a day.

I think you should vary your design and limit your running time to limited time periods like typical sports apps do.

Answer (score 0):

Make your service a [`Foreground service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) and show a persistent notification. It will almost never get killed. All reliable step counter apps show a persistent notification for the very same reason. Music players do it too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460417/why-does-android-keep-killing-my-service

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 6.0 doze mode has been introduced to reduce battery consumption by deferring background CPU and network activity for apps when the device is unused for long periods of time.

To confirm that doze mode is the reason for service not running,put your phone is doze mode forcefully by using command below and check if service runs(by setting time to few minutes later)

```
    $ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

We can also test by whitelisting application from doze mode. Manually configure the whitelist in Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization and choose your applciation.
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: If the problem was the Doze mode the process would stop after a few minutes or not more than an hour. The problem is that Android is not a server OS and there is no 100% guarantee that a service will not be killed. The probability of the service being killed during the first few hours is low but after 2 or 3 days becomes very high.