# alarm manager wakeup

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I tried to set a background "service" that, every minute, triggers an activity that do some stuff. I found the Alarm Manager class and I wrote this code based on Android doc:

```
Intent backg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckConnectivity.class);
boolean backgRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, backg, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
if(!backgRunning) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, backg, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
}
```

but the service is not triggered every minute, but it seems working only when the screen is off. Do you know why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `is not triggered every minute, but working only when the screen is off`? so it is working or not? what behavior do you have?

Comment: Work only when the screen is off, but also in this case, is not triggered every minute

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager are not reliable, that's why Android introduced **[Job Scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)**. But you can not use Job Scheduler < 21. So Android introduced **[Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)** in **Android Architecture Component.** Which handle your work internally by AlarmManager or JobScheduler.

Another good approach is to use **[Evernote's Jobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)**, which will use WorkManager from next version.

Finally I suggest you use **[Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)** instead of AlarmManager.

Also see [my explanation on Doze mode / Background restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587562/6891563).

Comment: Job scheduler seems perfect for me, also with the limitation <21. If I set a Job every X minutes, and the Job is already running, the old Job is deleted, right?

Comment: I read some doc about them, and I prefer JobScheduler. My background task is simple.

Comment: Yes, I know. Please, answer this. If I set a Job every X minutes, and the Job is already running, the old Job is deleted, right?